# Lagrange multiplier optimality condition

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

> Consider an equality constrained optimization problem
>   $$
> \underset{x\in\mathbb R^q}{\text{minimize}}f(x)\quad\text{subject to}\quad\ Ax=b,
> $$
>   where $f:\mathbb R^q\to\mathbb R$ is a convex differentiable objective function to be minimized, $A\in\mathbb R^{p\times q}$ and $b\in\mathbb R^{p}$.

I am trying to understand the proof of the Lagrange multiplier optimality condition
$$
\nabla f(x)+A^{\mathrm T}u=0
$$
for some $u\in\mathbb R^q$. According to first-order optimality condition, the solution $x\in\mathbb R^q$ satisfies $Ax=b$ and
$$
\nabla f(x)^{\mathrm T}(y-x)\ge0
$$
for all $y\in\mathbb R^q$ such that $Ay=b$. Since $A(y-x)=0$, $y-x\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$ and hence $\nabla f(x)^{\mathrm T}v\ge0$ for some $v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$. Why does it follow that $\nabla f(x)^{\mathrm T}(y-x)=0$ (it seems that we only have that it is greater or equal) and $\nabla f(x)^{\mathrm T}v=0$ for all $v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\nabla f(x)^{\mathrm T}v\ge0$, $\forall v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$, we have that $\nabla f(x)^{\mathrm T}v=0$, $\forall v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$ because if $v \in\operatorname{Null}(A)$, then $-v \in \operatorname{Null}(A)$.

Comment: How can we deduce that $\nabla f(x)^{\mathrm T}v\ge0$ for all $v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$? We have that $\nabla f(x)^{\mathrm T}(y-x)\ge0$ for some fixed $x$ such that $Ax=b$ and for all $y$ such that $Ay=b$. I might be missing something trivial here.

Comment: I think if $x$ and $y$ satisfy the system of linear equations, then $y-x$ is an element of the null space. On the other hand, if $x$ satisfies the system of equations and $v$ is an element of the null space, then $x+v$ also satisfies the system of equations

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now. We want to show that $\nabla f(x)^{T}v\ge0$ for all $v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$. Suppose that $y=v+x$. We have that $A(v+x)=Ax=b$ so this is a valid choice of $y$. This leads to $\nabla f(x)^{T}v\ge0$ for all $v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$. Since $\operatorname{Null}(A)$ is a linear space, $-v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$ as well and hence $-\nabla f(x)^{T}v\ge0$. So it follows that $\nabla f(x)^{T}v=0$ for all $v\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$.